# Two color line in gnuplot

Tags: color, gnuplot, plot

Is there any way to plot a line graph where each series is plotted with two alternating colors? For example, say I was plotting the population of bees over time and I wanted the line to alternate between black and yellow.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As the name of the site indicates, its purpose is for questions about typesetting systems built on top of TeX. Your question about gnuplot is probably better served on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: josh: I have to agree with @Carmdir. However, the question would be on-topic if you would rephrase it to plotting such a graph in general for a (La)TeX document. This would allow for TeX based plotting solutions.

Comment: I must admit to being a little surprised by this response. Gnuplot is of course a general purpose plotting tool, but it is primarily used to make figures in tex documents. The official gnuplot tutorial is about preparing gnuplot figures in tex! Searching for 'gnuplot' on this forum and superuser returns almost the same number of results (39 vs. 35).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot the concerned dataset first as a solid yellow line and then as a dashed black line. See the Gnuplot manual for the necessary settings.