# How can I draw a fancy "proxy" legend line with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have a couple of curves I am drawing in an axis, but one of them is a circle that is drawn with a  "fancy" line (I just overlay a thick black curve with a slightly thinner white dashed curve). Is there a way I can fake a legend entry to match?

I have looked in the pgfplots manual and I see `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry` but can't think of how to use it except for a rudimentary simple line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
% pgfplots package manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    width=10cm, height=6cm,
    font=\sffamily,
    ticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xmin=-0.7,xmax=0, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-1,-0.9,...,0}, minor xtick={-1,-0.95,...,0}, 
    ymin=0.7,ymax=1.0, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={0, 0.1,...,1}, minor ytick={0, 0.05,...,1},
    samples=500,domain=-1:0,
    grid=both,
    legend pos = south east,
    legend cell align = left,
    title={\large shapes on axis}]
        
  % I want to add a legend saying "circle"
  \draw [black, line width = 0.7mm] (0,0) circle [radius=1.0];
  \draw [white, line width = 0.5mm, dash pattern = on 5pt off 5pt] (0,0) circle [radius=1.0];
  \addlegendimage{black, line width=0.7mm};
  
  \addplot[blue, line width = 0.3mm]({x}, {1-0.5*x*x} ); 
  
  
  % I want to add a legend saying "line"
  \draw [green!50!black, line width=0.3mm] (-0.6,1) -- (-0.4,0.95);
  \addlegendimage{green!50!black, line width=0.3mm};
  
  \legend {circle, quadratic curve, line};
  

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make the circle legend have the same line pattern?

Comment: Yoou should be able to just use the same style. But in you case you draw two separate plots to obtain the fancy style. If you come up with a single style that daws you graph, then it should work.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but I don't know how to do that with a single style. I like the bent-striped-soda-straw look much better than a single line. There's no way to draw two different legend lines in the same spot? (without having to recreate the function of pgfplots legend)

Comment: One way would be to use a decoration on the path, but perhaps there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using option `postaction` (or `preaction`), the two `\draw`s can be merged to one. These two options are documented in `pgfmanual`, sec. 15.10 *Doing Multiple Actions on a Path* in v3.1.5b.

Similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16026/79060), an example using `postaction` is (note the option `draw` used in `postactions={...}`)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
      [postaction={draw, white, dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt, dash phase=4pt, thick}]
      [black, ultra thick] 
      (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By wrapping all the options in a new style `double colors`, your example can be drawn by (note the `dash phase=-4pt` added to `\addlegendimage[...]`)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\tikzset{
  double colors/.style={
    postaction={draw, white, line width = 0.5mm, dash pattern = on 5pt off 5pt},
    black, line width = 0.7mm
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    width=10cm, height=6cm,
    font=\sffamily,
    ticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xmin=-0.7,xmax=0, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-1,-0.9,...,0}, minor xtick={-1,-0.95,...,0}, 
    ymin=0.7,ymax=1.0, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={0, 0.1,...,1}, minor ytick={0, 0.05,...,1},
    samples=500,domain=-1:0,
    grid=both,
    legend pos = south east,
    legend cell align = left,
    title={\large shapes on axis}]
        
  % I want to add a legend saying "circle"
  \draw [double colors] (0,0) circle [radius=1.0];
  \addlegendimage{double colors, dash phase=-4pt, line width=0.7mm};
  
  \addplot[blue, line width = 0.3mm]({x}, {1-0.5*x*x} ); 
  
  % I want to add a legend saying "line"
  \draw [green!50!black, line width=0.3mm] (-0.6,1) -- (-0.4,0.95);
  \addlegendimage{green!50!black, line width=0.3mm};
  
  \legend {circle, quadratic curve, line};
  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I saved this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the takeaway here is that it is difficult (impossible?) to draw custom art in a legend; the cleaner approach in pgfplots is to encapsulate it as a style that can be applied to the line that the legend-handling logic can just use.

Comment: @JasonS Ah I just find the option `legend image code/.code={...}`, which can be used to set arbitrary drawing code for all legends. By default this option is set by `legend line` to `\draw plot coordinates {...};`. Not sure if there is an easy way to only change drawing code for specific legends.