# Alternating color borders of nodes and forest package

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, forest, alternating-colors

I try to follow [How to draw a double-color line with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/how-to-draw-a-double-color-line-with-tikz/703646#703646) and incorporate a node with alternating colors in the `forest` package. In classic `tikzpicture` and with `node` properties it works. However, for the `forest` package I am getting a weird result with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{%
/forest,
rbcirc/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,very thick,postaction={draw,red,dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,dash phase=2pt,very thick},text width=1.5em}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [A, rbcirc]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: red-circ]

If I comment out the postaction, then the black dashed pattern border is shown.

Comment: That is certainly an unusual looking tree ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the style as a Ti*k*Z style and it will work fine. You want these keys to be passed to Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{%
  rbcirc/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,very thick,postaction={draw,red,dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,dash phase=2pt,very thick},text width=1.5em}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [A, rbcirc
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: red-black bordered node in forest tree]

### Edit

I don't entirely understand what `forest` does here. For that, you'll have to ask somebody fluent in `forest`'s internal code. But I can say something about what's happening.

Consider the following sequence:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  rbcirc/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      draw,
      red,
      dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
  rbcirc 2/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      draw=red,
      dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc 2
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: rbcirc and rbcirc 2]

In the first case, it's as if we'd passed `red` to the node; in the second, it's as though we'd not passed it at all.

Now consider

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  rbcirc 3/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
      draw,
      red,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc 3
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This fails with the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: The key '/tikz/dash pattern' requires a value. I am go
ing to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.729 \end{forest}
                  
?
```

When `forest` encounters an unknown key, it passes it to Ti*k*Z *via* `unknown to` which is defined as equal to `node options`. If `rbcirc|rbcirc 2|rbcirc 3` is defined as a `forest` style, `rbcirc|rbcirc 2|rbcirc 3` is known to `forest`, so `forest` considers the key-value list which makes up the style. What seems to happen is that `forest` parses this key-value list as a comma-separated list, without regard to internal grouping. I suspect this is not quite right or more things would fail, but this appears to be the effect. So, for `rbcirc`, Ti*k*Z gets the list

```
anchor=base,circle=,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,very thick=,postaction=draw, red, dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick,,text width=1.5em
```

which is essentially

```
anchor=base,circle=,postaction=draw, red, dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick,,text width=1.5em
```

and we get a filled red circle with a dashed red border.

For `rbcirc 2`, the list of `node options` is

```
anchor=base,circle=,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,very thick=,postaction=draw=red, dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick,,text width=1.5em
```

which is basically

```
    anchor=base,circle=,fill=white,postaction=draw=red, dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick,,text width=1.5em
```

and we get a white node with a dashed black border.

But for `rbcirc 3` we get

```
anchor=base,circle=,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,very thick=,postaction=dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick, draw, red,,text width=1.5em
```

So the second `dash pattern` is interpreted as the value passed to `postaction` rather than as a key taking the value `on 2pt off 2pt`.

In contrast, if `rbcirc|rbcirc 2|rbcirc 3` are defined as Ti*k*Z styles, they are unknown to `forest` and therefore passed directly as `node options` to Ti*k*Z. In this case, the `node options` are

```
anchor=base,rbcirc=

anchor=base,rbcirc 2=
```

and

```
anchor=base,rbcirc 3=
```

so Ti*k*Z parses the definition of the styles as expected.

### Edit 2

In `forest.sty` we find

```
\pgfqkeys{/forest}{%
  .unknown/.code={%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter.\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \expandafter\forest@relatednode@option@setter\pgfkeyscurrentname=#1\forest@END
    \else
      \edef\forest@marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\forest@unknownto={\pgfkeyscurrentname=\unexpanded{#1}}}%
      }\forest@marshal
    \fi
  },
}
```

`\pgfkeyscurrentname=\unexpanded{#1}` is problematic because it basically passes the value back to the key without outer braces. If we double the braces in the input, we end up with a trailing `=` at the end i.e. `{<key>=<value>}=` which works, but presumably isn't officially sanctioned Ti*k*Z syntax.

Adding the following to the preamble fixes the issue **but I do NOT know if it is safe** and **do NOT recommend using it**.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/forest}{% DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME!
  .unknown/.code={%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter.\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \expandafter\forest@relatednode@option@setter\pgfkeyscurrentname=#1\forest@END
    \else
      \edef\forest@marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\forest@unknownto={\pgfkeyscurrentname={\unexpanded{#1}}}}%
      }\forest@marshal
    \fi
  },
}
\makeatother
```

For example,

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/forest}{% DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME!
  .unknown/.code={%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter.\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \expandafter\forest@relatednode@option@setter\pgfkeyscurrentname=#1\forest@END
    \else
      \edef\forest@marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\forest@unknownto={\pgfkeyscurrentname={\unexpanded{#1}}}}%
      }\forest@marshal
    \fi
  },
}
\makeatother
\forestset{%
  rbcirc/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      draw,
      red,
      dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
  rbcirc 2/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      draw=red,
      dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
  rbcirc 3/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    postaction={%
      dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
      dash phase=2pt,
      very thick,
      draw,
      red,
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
  rbcirc 4/.style={%
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw=black,
    dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
    very thick,
    {%
      postaction={%
        dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt,
        dash phase=2pt,
        very thick,
        draw,
        red,
      }%
    },
    text width=1.5em
  },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc 2
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc 3
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [A, rbcirc 4
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: alternating coloured border for forest node using forest style and perilously modified code]

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work as a `forest` style?

Comment: I am curious as well. Let us say, that you need to use a command, e.g., `child anchor=north` that is a command for the `forest` package. Then you cannot define it directly as a TikZ style, right?

Comment: @AlanMunn Not really. See above for my non-explanation.

Comment: @Arne Right, but then you define it as a `forest` style and it's fine. And many Ti*k*Z keys will work even in the definitions of `forest` styles. But some won't work there. In general, if a style is 'pure' Ti*k*Z, it is safer to make it a Ti*k*Z style. If it is a mix of `forest` and simple Ti*k*Z, a `forest` style is fine. If the Ti*k*Z is more complex, it's best to split the Ti*k*Z part off into its own style and just call that style within the definition of the `forest` style.

Comment: @cfr thanks for clarification!

Comment: @cfr Thanks! This pretty much matches my guesses, based on my having replicated much of your testing in my own tests.

Comment: @AlanMunn Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: @cfr Maybe. It's definitely misparsing the keys in a way. But that gave me an idea that works: if you simply put braces around the whole `postaction={...}`, i.e. use `{postaction={...}}` then the problem disappears!

Comment: @AlanMunn That doesn't really surprise me, though I didn't try it. I think forest splits the key from the value and then recombines them if the key is unknown. At that point, it uses `\noexpand` for the value, but it loses (or has already lost?) the outer braces. If you investigate that case, is it passed to Ti*k*Z as `{postaction={...}}=` or `postaction={...}=` by any chance?

Comment: @AlanMunn `node options` is indeed then `anchor=base,circle=,fill=white,draw=black,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,very thic
k=,postaction={dash pattern= on 2pt off 2pt, dash phase=2pt, very thick, draw, 
red, }=,text width=1.5em`. How safe is this? I was surprised that something like `postaction=draw=red` didn't give an error. Are there cases where that `<key>=<value>=<other value>` will cause problems?

Comment: @AlanMunn See edit 2. Is there a good reason not to do this, do you think?

Comment: @cfr I don't see any immediate problem. But it seems like this issue should be brought up with Sašo to adjudicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn Agreed. I really wanted to know if it looked obviously stupid.