# two-coloured strand with the knots library in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

I'm trying to draw a single link diagram (like the one here: https://loopspace.mathforge.org/HowDidIDoThat/TeX/Knots/#section.5) using the knots library:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
  flip crossing=2
]
\strand (1,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\strand[blue] (-1,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I'd like one of my circles to have two colours. The idea is that the link represents the closure of a three-strand braid, and one of the circles in the link comes from two of the strands, so I thought it would be nice to colour it to show that.

Initially, I was thinking of something like this: [How to draw a double-color line with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/how-to-draw-a-double-color-line-with-tikz) . However, when I changed my \strand[blue] to `\strand[draw=blue,dash pattern= on 3pt off 5pt,thick,postaction={draw,red,dash pattern= on 3pt off 5pt,dash phase=4pt,thick}](-1,0) circle[radius=2cm];`, the crossing gaps no longer show up:

[image]

I also tried an alternative approach using a gradient from this question [Path following color gradient in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz), but, again, the crossing gaps vanished.

I'm *assuming* the knot library is somehow not applying the gap rule to the postaction / decoration? Is there an appropriate way to draw a two-coloured strand using the knots library?

Comment: Why do you need `knot` library?  You can realize the drawing from scratch.

Comment: Things like a dash pattern should be put in the `only when rendering` key. The knots library uses a copy of the strand to "wipeout" the understand, so you don't want it to have gaps when it does so.

Comment: And I'm not sure I've ever investigated a postaction with strands. To be on the save side, I'd put that in the `only when rendering` key as well.

Comment: aha! so simple you when you know :-)

Comment: As a tip, setting `background colour=yellow` or some other non-background colour can be very useful to see what's going on.  This shows what the "cutting path" looks like.  Removing the `postaction` (as that has other issues) but keeping the `dash` pattern shows that the lower intersection point gets missed by the dash on the cutting path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
flip crossing=2,
clip width=10,
]
\strand[red, thick] (1,0) circle[radius=1.3cm];
\strand[
blue, thick,
only when rendering/.style={dash pattern=on 3pt off 5pt},
preaction={draw, red, thick, dash pattern=on 3pt off 5pt, dash phase=4pt},
](-0.5,0) circle[radius=1.3cm];
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two circle knot with red blue dash pattern]

Comment: thank you! it works perfectly

Comment: I note that you switched to a `preaction`.  I'm pretty sure that I've investigated this before (contrary to my comment on the question!) and found a difference in how pre and post actions work, to the effect that a postaction will clobber how `knots` works but a `preaction` won't.  I can't find the relevant `.tex` file in my folder of test files, though!

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I did not read your comments before posting my solution. I was just experimenting and found the needed `only when rendering` in the manual. I have no real idea of what I am doing - most of my solutions are just working experiments with no insight. Thanks for the `knots` package - it has solved many problems on this site.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I'm taking it as a win that you figured it out from the documentation - it's not one of my strengths ...